# How to identify and remove the SQL table rows that contains UTF 8 BOM characters

Tags: sql, utf-8, sql-server-2012

I  recently identified that some of the rows in our DB tables contains UTF 8 BOM (Byte Order Marking) characters (ï»¿).. Is there a way to identify those rows and removing the BOM characters from those rows? We are using SQL SERVER 2012.

Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: Please show us what you've tried

Comment: I haven't tried because I don't know how to identify such rows that has UTF-8 BOM characters..

Comment: What's the data type of the column varchar/nvarchar/char/nchar???

Comment: data type of column is nvarchar(max)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
CREATE TABLE #Testas 
(
   Col NVARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO #Testas (Col) VALUES ('ï»¿asd'), ('ï»¿etc')

UPDATE #Testas
SET Col = REPLACE(Col, N'ï»¿', '')

SELECT * FROM #Testas

DROP TABLE #Testas
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f62b/3)**

Comment: This doesn't work.. I tried.. when I try to search for columnVAlue like (%ï»¿%), it doesn't show anything..

Comment: Try It now, updated answer with `N`, `WHERE Col LIKE (N'%ï»¿%')`

Comment: Use only `SET Col = REPLACE(Col, N'ï»¿', '')`

Comment: No, It didn't work I tried these cmds
select * from test_table where fileNumber=102 and stringValue like N'0xEFBBBF%'
select * from test_table where fileNumber=102 and stringValue like N'ï»¿%'

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET table_column = REPLACE(table_column,'0xEFBBBF', '')
```

Comment: No, It didn't work I tried these cmds
select * from test_table where fileNumber=102 and stringValue like N'0xEFBBBF%'
select * from test_table where fileNumber=102 and stringValue like N'ï»¿%'

Comment: what output this query gives you: select CAST(left(stringValue,3) AS varchar), left(stringValue,3), stringValue, * from test_table

Comment: When we convert to varchar it shows "?", the original datatype is nvarchar (but it doesn't display BOM character in ssms , If I copy to notepad++ and change the encoding to UTF8 BOM then it shows the BOM characters)

output of above command you gave is this,
?02 02 021210010065
?02 02 021210010065

Comment: Finally got the required query

select * from  test_table where fileNumber=102 and CAST(left(stringValue,1) AS varchar)='?'

Comment: Finally, got it
 select *, SUBSTRING( CAST(CAST(stringValue AS varchar) AS nvarchar), 2, LEN(stringValue))  from test_table where fileNumber=102 and CAST(left(stringValue,1) AS varchar)='?'

 update test_table set stringValue=SUBSTRING( CAST(CAST(stringValue AS varchar) AS nvarchar), 2, LEN(stringValue)) where fileNumber=102 and CAST(left(stringValue,1) AS varchar)='?'

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it,

```
select *, SUBSTRING( CAST(CAST(stringValue AS varchar) AS nvarchar), 2, LEN(stringValue))  from test_table where fileNumber=102 and CAST(left(stringValue,1) AS varchar)='?'

update test_table set stringValue=SUBSTRING( CAST(CAST(stringValue AS varchar) AS nvarchar), 2, LEN(stringValue)) where fileNumber=102 and CAST(left(stringValue,1) AS varchar)='?'
```